# user id does not work with email

Tags: box-api

As per the below link
[using the v2 box api: how do I get a user id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14046216/using-the-v2-box-api-how-do-i-get-a-user-id/14047555#14047555)

the email should work as id for collaboration but when I am trying to use it with email id it fails with following error, and it work fine when i use the account ID

please note I have replaced the actual email id with  in the response

```
{
"type": "error",
"status": 404,
"code": "not_found",
"context_info": {
    "errors": [
        {
            "reason": "invalid_parameter",
            "name": "id",
            "message": "Invalid value '<my email id>'. 'id' with value '<my emmail id>' not found"
        }
    ]
},
"help_url": "http://developers.box.com/docs/#errors",
"message": "Not Found",
"request_id": "183660525751e95b3044f1d"
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the JSON you're sending in this request?

Comment: Here is the JSON I am sending

{"item": { "id": "<my folde id>", "type": "folder"}, "accessible_by": { "id": "<my email id>"}, "role": "editor"}

please note I have replaced the actual email id and the actual folder id in avobe JSON

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in the JSON you're sending. Currently you have:

```
{
    "item": {
        "id": "YOUR_FOLDER_ID",
        "type": "folder"
    },
    "accessible_by": {
        "id": "YOUR_EMAIL"
    },
    "role": "editor"
}
```

If you're using an email address instead of a user id, it should be with the `login` attribute i.e.

```
{
    "item": {
        "id": "YOUR_FOLDER_ID",
        "type": "folder"
    },
    "accessible_by": {
        "login": "YOUR_EMAIL"
    },
    "role": "editor"
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !!

and I am sorry, I missed the login attribute